# Swift button created programmatically needs to have 2 lines for title

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uibutton

I am creating buttons programmatically like this:

```
let stage: Stages = stagesObjectsArray[i]
let button = UIButton(type: .Custom) as UIButton        
button.setTitle(stage.name, forState: .Normal)
button.sizeToFit()
button.frame.origin = buttonPosition
let buttonIncrement = button.frame.size.width + padding.width
buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "", size: widthOfScreen/3.2)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.tag = stage.id
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GamesAllViewController.buttonPressedTopMenu(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
buttonView.addSubview(button)
```

What I want to implement and can't figure out how is to have the title of the button on 2 rows if the width of the button becomes too big(for instance more than half the width of the screen).

I have found some questions on this topic, but they all assume they know the title of the button, while in my case it is dynamic and I do not know what it might be.

I have tried this code, but with no change:

```
button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 2
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "\n" and NoOFLines to 0

try this code

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    let button = UIButton(type: .Custom) as UIButton
    button.setTitle("Line 1\nLine 2", forState: .Normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
    button.titleLabel!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    button.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 40)
    button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    button.addTarget(self, action: "methodName:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)

}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not know the title of the button previously, it comes from the server, I can not possible know where to introduce \n

Comment: In that case you have to calculate UIButton's width dynamically by data from server and keep numberOfLines = 0 else you can make a trick, use UIView with textView / label interaction false and button button on it then as per server data you have to set frame for UIView , also make cliptoBounds true for UIView.

Comment: Did you found any solution?